# build nginx use autoconf

Tags: nginx, makefile, autoconf

recently I'm reading nginx source code, but I got confused how to build it's code by autoconf, I have try my best to write a Makefile.am, unfortunate, I'm failed to write a correct Makefile.am file, so I cann't get a configure file, does anybody know how to write a Makefile.am?

Answer (score 1):

I know how to write a `Makefile.am`, but you have no need to.

As you know, the `nginx` source package is a GNU autotools
package.

*You* don't do the autotooling. The people who write `nginx` do that. When you
download the source package, the `configure.ac`, the `Makefile.am`(s) and other
autotools files are already there along with all the source code.

To build the package, all you have to do is run the `configure` script to
generate correct makefiles for your system, then run `make`. (This is why the
build system is called `autotools`.)

Source packages are distributed from `http://nginx.org/download/`. Assuming
you want `nginx 1.10.2` (the stable release at this time), you simply do this
in a suitable working directory:

```
$ wget http://nginx.org/download/nginx-1.10.2.tar.gz
$ tar zxf nginx-1.10.2.tar.gz
$ cd nginx-1.10.2
$ ./configure
$ make
```

Then it's built in `./nginx-1.10.2`. If you then want to install `nginx` in your system, continue:

```
$ sudo make install
```

Building any autotooled source package is essential the same as this.

For full details and variations, *do* read [NSTALLING NGINX OPEN SOURCE](https://www.nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/installing-nginx-open-source/)

Comment: thanks a lot,I know ./configure then make, what made curious is use autoconf to generate a configure file, I have written a letter to nginx writer, he said he write this configure file by hand, I have try to write some Makefile.am, but failed

Answer (score 0):

I have write a email to nginx's author, he said configure file was written by hand